# How to execute location from background in certain Time interval in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am making one application in which the location needs to be updated after every 2 hours from background, i have implemented CLLocationManager and it is working absolutely fine and is calling , however if i implement timer from background for certain time interval it didn't work and if i put the app in sleep mode for that few seconds like 300, it awakes twice or thrice not more than that,when the home button is pressed i stopped the location and after sleep it again start the location update and then again stop ,so how it is possible to get the proper location update after 2 hours plz help

Comment: hey .. did you got some solution to your problem.Even I am facing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for updating the Location every 2 hours..

Instances of UILocalNotification represent notifications that an application can schedule for presentation to its users at specific dates and times. The operating system is responsible for delivering the notification at the proper time; the application does not have to be running for this to happen.

Comment: UILocalNotification, how it will work for background execution

Comment: See this link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html every thing is clear here..